# Trying to get SBUS Signals With STM32F407vg

Tags: embedded, stm32, stm32f4discovery, usart, motordriver

I am quite new to this type of hobby and I have been trying to make land drone using STM32F407vg as mcu and Radiolink T8FB(BT) / R8EF for rx/tx.

I wanted to use Sbus protocol for controlling the drone and tinkered some code.

Could you please check my code and point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2023 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "usb_host.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include"stdio.h"
#include "lcd.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;

SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim1;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_usart2_rx;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
volatile int i=0,cntrl =0;
volatile uint16_t ch[9], ch1=0, ch2=0, ch3=0, ch4=0, ch5=0, ch6=0, ch7=0, ch8=0;
volatile uint16_t prevtime,current_time,elapsedtime;
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
void MX_USB_HOST_Process(void);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
int x=0;
char  rec_sbus_data[22];
int sbus_channel[12];

int _channels[19];
uint8_t buffer[24]={0};
uint8_t buffer_index = 0;
uint8_t startByte=0x0F, endByte=0x01;


void move(char direction[],int strength)
{
    //10 11 left 12 13 right
    //10 13 fw
    //11 12 bk


    if(direction=="forward")
    {
        TIM1->CCR1=strength;

        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_11,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_12,GPIO_PIN_RESET);

        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_10,GPIO_PIN_SET);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_13,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    }
    else if (direction=="back")
    {
        TIM1->CCR1=strength;


                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_10,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_13,GPIO_PIN_RESET);

                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_11,GPIO_PIN_SET);
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_12,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    }
    else if(direction=="forward_right")
    {
        TIM1->CCR1=strength;
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_10,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_11,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_12,GPIO_PIN_RESET);

        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_13,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    }
    else if(direction=="forward_left")
    {
        TIM1->CCR1=strength;
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_11,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_11,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_13,GPIO_PIN_RESET);

        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_10,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    }
    else if(direction=="stop")
    {
               TIM1->CCR1=0;
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_10,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_11,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_12,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE,GPIO_PIN_13,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    }

}

void readSbus()
{
while(1)
{
    HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart2,(uint8_t*)buffer,25);
if(buffer_index==0 && buffer[0]!=startByte)
{
printf("buffer 0");
    continue;
}
buffer_index++;


if(buffer_index==25)
{
    buffer_index = 0;

if(buffer_index==24 && buffer[24]!=endByte)
{
    printf("buffer 24");
    continue;
}

_channels[0]  = ((buffer[1]    |buffer[2]<<8)                 & 0x07FF);
            _channels[1]  = ((buffer[2]>>3 |buffer[3]<<5)                 & 0x07FF);
            _channels[2]  = ((buffer[3]>>6 |buffer[4]<<2 |buffer[5]<<10)  & 0x07FF);
            _channels[3]  = ((buffer[5]>>1 |buffer[6]<<7)                 & 0x07FF);
            _channels[4]  = ((buffer[6]>>4 |buffer[7]<<4)                 & 0x07FF);
            _channels[5]  = ((buffer[7]>>7 |buffer[8]<<1 |buffer[9]<<9)   & 0x07FF);
            _channels[6]  = ((buffer[9]>>2 |buffer[10]<<6)                & 0x07FF);
            _channels[7]  = ((buffer[10]>>5|buffer[11]<<3)                & 0x07FF);
            _channels[8]  = ((buffer[12]   |buffer[13]<<8)                & 0x07FF);
            _channels[9]  = ((buffer[13]>>3|buffer[14]<<5)                & 0x07FF);
            _channels[10] = ((buffer[14]>>6|buffer[15]<<2|buffer[16]<<10) & 0x07FF);
            _channels[11] = ((buffer[16]>>1|buffer[17]<<7)                & 0x07FF);
            _channels[12] = ((buffer[17]>>4|buffer[18]<<4)                & 0x07FF);
            _channels[13] = ((buffer[18]>>7|buffer[19]<<1|buffer[20]<<9)  & 0x07FF);
            _channels[14] = ((buffer[20]>>2|buffer[21]<<6)                & 0x07FF);
            _channels[15] = ((buffer[21]>>5|buffer[22]<<3)                & 0x07FF);
            _channels[16] =   buffer[23] & 0x01;
            _channels[17] =   buffer[23] & 0x02;
            _channels[18] =   buffer[23] & 0x04;
            _channels[19] =   buffer[23] & 0x08;





            /*(((buffer[23])      & 0x0001) ? _channels[16] = 2047: _channels[16] = 0;
                        ((buffer[23] >> 1) & 0x0001) ? _channels[17] = 2047: _channels[17] = 0;  */
}
}
}

void printLcd(char *text) {

    // Lcd_PortType ports[] = { D4_GPIO_Port, D5_GPIO_Port, D6_GPIO_Port, D7_GPIO_Port };
    Lcd_PortType ports[] = { GPIOE, GPIOE, GPIOE, GPIOC };
    // Lcd_PinType pins[] = {D4_Pin, D5_Pin, D6_Pin, D7_Pin};
    Lcd_PinType pins[] = { GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_13 };
    Lcd_HandleTypeDef lcd;
    // Lcd_create(ports, pins, RS_GPIO_Port, RS_Pin, EN_GPIO_Port, EN_Pin, LCD_4_BIT_MODE);
    lcd = Lcd_create(ports, pins, GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_4,
            LCD_4_BIT_MODE);
    Lcd_cursor(&lcd, 0, 1);

    Lcd_string(&lcd, text);
    HAL_Delay(1000);




}
void printLcd_Int(int val) {

    // Lcd_PortType ports[] = { D4_GPIO_Port, D5_GPIO_Port, D6_GPIO_Port, D7_GPIO_Port };
    Lcd_PortType ports[] = { GPIOE, GPIOE, GPIOE, GPIOC };
    // Lcd_PinType pins[] = {D4_Pin, D5_Pin, D6_Pin, D7_Pin};
    Lcd_PinType pins[] = { GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_13 };
    Lcd_HandleTypeDef lcd;
    // Lcd_create(ports, pins, RS_GPIO_Port, RS_Pin, EN_GPIO_Port, EN_Pin, LCD_4_BIT_MODE);
    lcd = Lcd_create(ports, pins, GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_4,
            LCD_4_BIT_MODE);
    Lcd_cursor(&lcd, 0, 1);

    Lcd_string(&lcd, "INPUT:");
    Lcd_int(&lcd, val);
    HAL_Delay(1000);

}


/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_USB_HOST_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1,TIM_CHANNEL_1);



  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
    MX_USB_HOST_Process();

    HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart2,(uint8_t*)rec_sbus_data,22);

    sbus_channel[0]  = ((rec_sbus_data[1]|rec_sbus_data[2]<<8) & 0x07FF);
          sbus_channel[1]  = ((rec_sbus_data[2]>>3 |rec_sbus_data[3]<<5)                 & 0x07FF);
          sbus_channel[2]  = ((rec_sbus_data[3]>>6 |rec_sbus_data[4]<<2 |rec_sbus_data[5]<<10)  & 0x07FF);
          sbus_channel[3]  = ((rec_sbus_data[5]>>1 |rec_sbus_data[6]<<7)                 & 0x07FF);
          sbus_channel[4]  = ((rec_sbus_data[6]>>4 |rec_sbus_data[7]<<4)                 & 0x07FF);
          sbus_channel[5]  = ((rec_sbus_data[7]>>7 |rec_sbus_data[8]<<1 |rec_sbus_data[9]<<9)   & 0x07FF);
          sbus_channel[6]  = ((rec_sbus_data[9]>>2 |rec_sbus_data[10]<<6)                & 0x07FF);
          sbus_channel[7]  = ((rec_sbus_data[10]>>5|rec_sbus_data[11]<<3)                & 0x07FF);
          sbus_channel[8]  = ((rec_sbus_data[12]   |rec_sbus_data[13]<<8)                & 0x07FF);
          sbus_channel[9]  = ((rec_sbus_data[13]>>3|rec_sbus_data[14]<<5)                & 0x07FF);
          sbus_channel[10] = ((rec_sbus_data[14]>>6|rec_sbus_data[15]<<2|rec_sbus_data[16]<<10) & 0x07FF);
          sbus_channel[11] = ((rec_sbus_data[16]>>1|rec_sbus_data[17]<<7)                & 0x07FF);
          sbus_channel[12] =0;
          sbus_channel[12] =0;
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    //move("forward",100);

}

  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 7;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief I2C1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 1 */
  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 100000;
  hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief SPI1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 1 */
  /* SPI1 parameter configuration*/
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};
  TIM_IC_InitTypeDef sConfigIC = {0};
  TIM_BreakDeadTimeConfigTypeDef sBreakDeadTimeConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 1 */
  htim1.Instance = TIM1;
  htim1.Init.Prescaler = 42000-1;
  htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim1.Init.Period = 100-1;
  htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim1.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim1, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_IC_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCNPolarity = TIM_OCNPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  sConfigOC.OCIdleState = TIM_OCIDLESTATE_RESET;
  sConfigOC.OCNIdleState = TIM_OCNIDLESTATE_RESET;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigIC.ICPolarity = TIM_INPUTCHANNELPOLARITY_RISING;
  sConfigIC.ICSelection = TIM_ICSELECTION_DIRECTTI;
  sConfigIC.ICPrescaler = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
  sConfigIC.ICFilter = 0;
  if (HAL_TIM_IC_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigIC, TIM_CHANNEL_4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateRunMode = TIM_OSSR_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateIDLEMode = TIM_OSSI_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.LockLevel = TIM_LOCKLEVEL_OFF;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.DeadTime = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakState = TIM_BREAK_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakPolarity = TIM_BREAKPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.AutomaticOutput = TIM_AUTOMATICOUTPUT_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_ConfigBreakDeadTime(&htim1, &sBreakDeadTimeConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim1);

}

/**
  * @brief USART2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 100000;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Stream5_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Stream5_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Stream5_IRQn);

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, CS_I2C_SPI_Pin|D4_Pin|D5_Pin|D6_Pin
                          |GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(D7_GPIO_Port, D7_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(OTG_FS_PowerSwitchOn_GPIO_Port, OTG_FS_PowerSwitchOn_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, LD4_Pin|LD3_Pin|LD5_Pin|LD6_Pin
                          |Audio_RST_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, E_Pin|RS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : CS_I2C_SPI_Pin D4_Pin D5_Pin D6_Pin
                           PE10 PE11 PE12 PE13 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = CS_I2C_SPI_Pin|D4_Pin|D5_Pin|D6_Pin
                          |GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : D7_Pin OTG_FS_PowerSwitchOn_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = D7_Pin|OTG_FS_PowerSwitchOn_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PDM_OUT_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = PDM_OUT_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI2;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(PDM_OUT_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : B1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_EVT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(B1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : I2S3_WS_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = I2S3_WS_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF6_SPI3;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(I2S3_WS_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : BOOT1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = BOOT1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(BOOT1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : CLK_IN_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = CLK_IN_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF5_SPI2;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(CLK_IN_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : LD4_Pin LD3_Pin LD5_Pin LD6_Pin
                           Audio_RST_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LD4_Pin|LD3_Pin|LD5_Pin|LD6_Pin
                          |Audio_RST_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : I2S3_MCK_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = I2S3_MCK_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF6_SPI3;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(I2S3_MCK_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : OTG_FS_OverCurrent_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = OTG_FS_OverCurrent_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(OTG_FS_OverCurrent_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : E_Pin RS_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = E_Pin|RS_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : MEMS_INT2_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = MEMS_INT2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_EVT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(MEMS_INT2_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

Values I recieve from the reciever are all over the place, can't get a stable number from any of the channels. It ranges 248 to 2100 without doing anything(not touching the controller).

P.S. same thing happens in ppm/pwm protocols.

Comment: `HAL_UART_Receive_DMA()` just starts the DMA, it does not wait until it has completed. You'd be as well just using the regular polled receive, `HAL_UART_Receive()`, which does wait until all the data has been received.

Comment: If that has fixed it for you let me know and I'll post a more complete answer.

Comment: It is still unstable I am afraid...